# Interract with a .exe program with js instead of typing in the program

Tags: node.js, powershell, stdin, executable, external-process

Hello I'm tryna make a Skyrim server Dashboard.

The server look like this => [image: It seems like a way of terminal (i don't know)]

On this server i can type some command like this =>[image]
when I manualy wrote `/help` and it show the output.

I tried to run the executable in node js, the server is working, I can join it, And I can see the output on my VSCode Terminal

But I can't input some text or command

[image]

Hope you can help me thanks in advance.
##Its my first ask

Answer (score 0):

Add `shell: true` to the spawn method so you can still pass commands to the process.

```js
const child = require('child_process').spawn("C:/SkyrimTogetherServer.exe", {
    shell: true
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I tried but it still didnt wortk

Comment: Have you tried adding `stdio: 'inherit'` together with `shell: true`?

Comment: I tried after you answered and i got this error: ` child.stdin.write('tratata\n'); TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'write')`  Thanks for you're answer

Comment: I'll try replicating your setup when I have the time. :) I also play Skyrim with buttloads of mods.